# Rename files in directory with CMD in loop in reverse order

Tags: windows, cmd

There are four files in directory: 12_1.txt, 12_2.txt, 12_3.txt, 12_4.txt. I need to rename them **(using command "ren" or "rename")** so, that:

12_1.txt would be the 12-4.txt

12_2.txt would be the 12-3.txt

12_3.txt would be the 12-2.txt

12_4.txt would be the 12-1.txt

***I'm tried to do something like that:***

```
set /a pos=0 & set /a length=5 & for %x in (*) do 
@(set /a pos+=1 & set /a length-=1 & ren 12_%length%.* 12-%pos%.* >nul)
```

But it **did not work** and only one file was renamed, befause of "ren" command always saw one value for the variables the last one that the loop gave. I think I wrote a lot of superfluous there. My knowledge in cmd is at the level of 7% of 100.

Comment: This is sounding a bit like homework. Are the `_#` names all sequential numeric with no breaks?

Comment: You  appear not to be using delayed expansion. Additionally your opening parenthesis should be on the same line as your `do` statement, as you've indicated that one file was renamed, that must be a typo, which you should correct.

Answer (score -1):

This can at least sort the names in reverse order and output it to a text file,

then you can copy over those lines for renaming or copieing purposes:

dir /b /O:-N > files2.txt